# CsvHelper Looking for Non-existent Columns

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

**The propblem:**  There is no "Name" field in the object or csv file, yet CsVHelper keeps looking for "Name" in the header. So why is it tripping there and what are some fixes?

When trying to build objects from a csv file, the following error comes up:

```
CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: Header with name 'Name' was not found. If you are expecting some headers to be missing and want to ignore this validation, set the configuration HeaderValidated to null. You can also change the functionality to do something else, like logging the issue.
   at CsvHelper.Configuration.ConfigurationFunctions.HeaderValidated(Boolean isValid, String[] headerNames, Int32 headerNameIndex, ReadingContext context)
```

I have tried setting HeaderValidated to null, but got the same results.

The header of the csv:
`Id|Title|Description|AssignedToUserId|SourceUserId|DateCreated|DateAssigned|DateCompleted|Notes`

The parsing code:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetCSVData<T>(string fullFileName)
{
    PrintMembers<T>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fullFileName))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            csv.Configuration.IncludePrivateMembers = false;
            csv.Parser.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";

            var records = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
            return records;
        }
    }
}
```

A quick function for listing the public properties and fields of the class (T) being passed in outputs the following:

```
Properties...
        Id
        AssignedToUserId
        SourceUserId
        Title
        Description
        AssignedTo
        Source
        DateCreated
        DateAssigned
        DateCompleted
        RelatedTasks
        Notes
Fields...
        [None]
```

They all have getters and setters.

**EDIT**

The IntermediateTask is the generic being fed into GetCSVData().  It has a default constructor.  IntermediateTask is internal, but is in the same assembly as GetCSVData().

Code for the class(es) in question:

```
internal class IntermediateTask : Task
{
    private int _Id;
    new public int Id 
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }

    private int _AssignedToUserId;
    public int AssignedToUserId
    {
        get { return _AssignedToUserId; }
        set 
        {
            _AssignedToUserId = value;
            base.AssignedTo = userManager.Get(_AssignedToUserId); 
        }
    }

    private int _SourceUserId;
    public int SourceUserId
    {
        get { return _SourceUserId; }
        set 
        {
            this._SourceUserId = value;
            base.Source = userManager.Get(_SourceUserId); 
        }
    }

    public IntermediateTask() : base("", "", new IntermediateUser(), new IntermediateUser())
    {
    }
}


public class Task
{
    public Task(string title, string description, User assignedTo, User source, DateTime? dateCreated = null, int id = 0)
    {
        this.RelatedTasks = new List<Task>();
        this.Title = title;
        this.Description = description;
        this.AssignedTo = assignedTo;
        this.Source = source;
        this.DateCreated = dateCreated ?? DateTime.Now;
        this.Id = id;
    }
    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        protected set { _Id = value; }
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public User Source { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAssigned { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public IList<Task> RelatedTasks { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    
    override public string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id:  {Id};  Title:  {Title}";
    }
}
```

Comment: what's T in your case?

Comment: Please add code for the type you are reading your csv to.

Comment: Does T have a default (parameter-less) constructor defined?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it complained about AssignedTo missing, but that is actually a property in the class that is not in the csv, so I had to add these two lines to make it work:

```
csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
```

I don't know why it would come up with 'Name' unless you have something different.

Comment: I've played with those and more flags, too, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Without looking at your file, I can't really tell what's going on. I assume you are passing Task as the type to CsvHelper, and all properties match all headers. If all of these are true then look into the file content, like double quotes or lack thereof when needed.

Comment: the relevant classes and the code for the parser have been posted.

Comment: it works for me (meaning no error) with the two lines I stated in my answer. How you configured your classes and whether that is the right way of doing it, is a totally different topic. To me it doesn't look clean, but the parser doesn't care about that, and so your question is why you get that error, and I'm telling you CsvHelper is able to parse my fake csv file with the same headers and the same classes, minus the usermanager code and whatever User class I came up with. I'm using the latest version of CsvHelper.